# Combining filter and must in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-dsl

What is the difference between adding a query filter inside a must and having a query filter and a must separately?

I need to apply a filter query to a search for but either of these two queries works the same for me. I would like to know if there are any differences.

Case 1:

```
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "field": {
              "value": "VALUE"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "filter": [
              {
                "script": {
                  "script": {
                    "source": """
                  return true;
                  
                """
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Case 2:

```
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "field": {
              "value": "VALUE"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": [
              {
                "script": {
                  "script": {
                    "source": """
                  return true;
                  
                """
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
    }
  }
```

In my opinion they do not differ, but I need references. Greetings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Both the query will work exactly the same**

Refer to documentation on the [boolean query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) to know more about your structure

> must: The clause (query) must appear in matching documents and will
> contribute to the score.
>
> filter: The clause (query) must appear in matching documents. However
> unlike must the score of the query will be ignored. Filter clauses are
> executed in filter context, meaning that scoring is ignored and
> clauses are considered for caching.

Structure of your first query where multiple bool queries are combined:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {},
          "bool": {
            "filter": {
              "script": {}
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Structure of your second query that includes single bool query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {}
        }
      ],
      "filter": [
        {
          "script": {}
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**As you can see, in both the search queries the document will match only when both the term query and script query condition is satisfied**

Answer (score 0):

They both will work exactly the same, second one would be preferred syntax because it's not as nested as first one and easier to read.